# Shortest "arithmetic" formula to output 1000 primes

Tags: arithmetic, primes, atomic-code-golf

Write a formula using only the digits `0-9`, `+`, `*`, `-`, `/`, `%` and `^` to output a 1000 *distinct* primes when given input (which can be used as a variable `n` in the formula) of numbers 1 to 1000. (Note that `/` will give the quotient as all arithmetic is integer arithmetic.) Solutions can use `(` and `)` freely and they will not be counted in the length.

The shortest formula wins! The primes only need to be *some* 1000 primes not necessarily the first 1000.

**EDIT**

Edited for clarity based on suggestions by [Sisyphus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48931/sisyphus) and [an earlier question on primality testing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/170398/primality-testing-formula).

Symbols are meant to work with integers in the "usual" way as follows.

`n`
:    Represents a number from 1 to 1000 which is the "input" to the formula. It can be used any number of times in the formula and it will represent the same input.

`0-9`
:    Sequences of digits (terminated by non `0-9` symbols or  ) return the number represented by this decimal representation. Negation of an expression can be represented as `(-`{expression}`)`

`+`
:    Returns the sum of two numbers

`*`
:    Returns the product of two numbers

`/`
:    Returns the integer quotient of two numbers

`%`
:    Returns the remainder on division of the first number by the second number. This and `/` follow Euclidean division conventions.

`-`
:    Returns the result of subtracting the second number from the first number.

`^`
:    Returns the power of the first number by the second number. Anything to the power 0 is taken as 1 including 0!

`()`
:    Brackets are used in pairs to encapsulate an expression that returns a number using the previous rules.

Comment: May we use `0<=n<1000` instead of `0<n<=1000`?

Comment: Related: [Primality testing formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/170398/20260)

Comment: Each of the operator symbols you list represents an operation which yields one value. How is a formula to output 1000 values?

Comment: @RosieF the formula should be defined on `n` which is a number from 1 to 1000 that should output the 1000 primes

Comment: do the 1000 primes need to be in order; that is, should `f(x)>f(y)` for all `x>y`

Comment: Is a formula an expression that results in a prime or is it an equation that is only true for primes?

Comment: Can we use negative numbers as exponents with `^`? This would allow using rational numbers, which I'm not sure you want.

Comment: Since the allowed operations suffice to [compute operations in the class ELEMENTARY](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=ELEMENTARY#Basis_for_ELEMENTARY), as I describe in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204949/20260), it should actually be possible to give a fully general formula for the `n`'th prime for any `n`, not just up to 1000. I suspect this would be shorter than hardcoding information for 1000 primes. It may also be possible to modify [Lopsy's primality-testing approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/171453/20260) to give the n'th prime.

Comment: (These are ideas for approaches that I don't have time to develop now. Anyone can feel free to use them.)

Comment: if this is [tag:atomic-code-golf] what is the winning criterion?

Comment: May we assume \$0^0=1\$?

Comment: @xnor I wouldn't count on the formula being shorter. As a test, I tried creating a formula for a bitwise AND using the formalism of [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1134/S1990478907030106), and it adds up to 358,191 bytes and doesn't even currently work! The main problem is that expressions inside finite sums have to be broken down into Diophantine equations with dozens of auxiliary variables, and each power combination of these variables has to be separately considered. Another issue is that some of the intermediate values can be in the double or triple exponentials wrt the input.

Answer (score 17):

## Score <s>1164</s> <s>883</s> <s>835</s> <s>772</s> <s>601</s> <s>574</s> <s>554</s> 506

```
541^n*743^(n/2)*(-1)^(n/4)*17^(n/8)%2310+297999352693782350435634574256421873511169209139789986107407037031463672744907435566931682004950168827622126589004268258979810886896053712313147567393521260370898856430728936238509646240927399434529133911694916958518274696252190810912239170743768597920487389824644988723446125401158124982957878348425345764310640796665180984553241724855646631162669954988652785474199384658696484753453854147610893664426900411229033105555630617039087023847065224114331551958/67^(n%250)%67*2310
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NZLNjtNAEITvPMVcVrINKP3/g8SbcAkigUgbJ8rmEiGePZRZYVlWz7hV/VXNXB/3X5dVn8fb5TzeHufrY5zO18vtPk5v19vpfPhwHF/H6/78/cd@rF/Gt6cbL8u6pOmyTOtuJ/Myfeb5fWHzwvle1vwiyvRROrtbXaI1S9TJ1EPN08TDhCvVmTlaqFk7q7uCKY2SFC9baKSkWWNT3QNKHCVE1k6oSjJEWMKrsSn4hyq7mKqiOsg1GTTQSo/UDQftm3x1FTCUUqo1RMupw0KMWtDZBlQBmPbGaI2PlzNmWnQIhJowqFkELbkhZpRjvJDBGwaIBeCrUtQsWNyI2YsFm9KelaVWiGNLBSxMAfMdEZhDXeauYpxiBfcWoUARxNC@yYZLllsaI@cypAAw6OWmBz8G1wh0swcOnAMyYuA2KUY5nlAKoCucJCECS4IoRrKhxZ1hebeLfyf7Ik7zC@rtdJ@4I@t9ej2s0@/jtM7jeLmNdZzWcduvPw8TfxpMxPM4Hf9fqGnrm//M8/Mv)

(OP hasn’t answered my [question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/212254/shortest-arithmetic-formula-to-output-1000-primes/212266#comment499623_212254) about the behavior of `/` and `%` on negative numbers, so this answer works under the floored or Euclidean [conventions](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/divmodnote-letter.pdf) where `(-1) % 2310 = 2309`.)

Comment: Can you explain the comment in the end?

Comment: @PedroA It's not a comment, it's just that the integer division operator is `//` in Python 3.

Comment: @Neil Which incidentally means that the real score is 775.

Comment: @Arnauld Actually by my count his score is 772.

Comment: Oops, corrected.

Comment: Impressive. Since you import isprime in the header, you might as well use it in the footer : `print(all(isprime(f(n+1)) for n in range(1000)))`.

Comment: @EricDuminil I’m not sure how I lost that, fixed. (The set is important to check distinctness, though.)

Comment: @AndersKaseorg: Sure. My line would have been added after yours, but your modification is better.

Answer (score 17):

## Score <s>424</s> 193

```
(30*n+(1-(1/(2^(n*30+16)%(n*30+17))))*((1-(1/(2^(n*30+22)%(n*30+23))))*((1-(1/(2^(n*30+28)%(n*30+29))))*((1-(1/(2^(n*30+12)%(n*30+13))))*((1-(1/(2^(n*30+6)%(n*30+7))))*((1-(1/(2^(n*30+40)%(n*30+41))))*((1-(1/(2^(n*30+18)%(n*30+19))))*(882)-22)+34)-6)-16)+6)+6)+17)+(1/(1+(n-475)^2))*10
```

This code searches the first Fermat pseudoprime of the form `n*30+d`, with offset d from `{17,23,29,13,7,11,19,1}`. The 4 cases where this fails (nothing found or pseudoprime found that is not a prime) are fixed a posteriori.

The order in which the offsets are testet was handcrafted as to minimize the number of pseudoprimes.

The following building blocks where used to yield boolean values: `1/t` yields the truth value of `t==1` (when we know that `t` is positive), `1/(1+(n-t)^2)` yields the truth value of `n==t`.

`b1*t1+(1-b1)*( b2*t2+(1-b2)*( b3*t3+(1-b3)*(...)))` mimics the code

```
if b1: t1
else if b2: t2
else if b3: t3
...
```

**Edit**: I could't resist to optimize.
Key tricks:

- the if-else now returns only the offset, the final result is call afterwards.
- xnors latest if-else gadget vastly reduced code size
- the resulting nested expression had adjacend summands that could be  contracted
- no Fermat test for the last index, as on failure it must be corrected anyway
- grid offsets reduced the number of faulty cases to 1

[Verification program](https://tio.run/##dZHBboMwEETvfMVeqqzt0ngNTWil/EkvpIHWEl4s4xxQlG@nViBcKiwffHgzO7P2Y/ztuZja0DsYRudHsM73IYIdfLCuydpTV7vzpQb@/Jqw0JIVUo6036ORElkWWtFBvCyvo0hH4j/EmCdiii2kWpGPDYRWF9pyWaNsJSn1kyhpa8yahJYkVWVEnjqoohT5QeSpsZpvaqwealLIeXl8F1KaJCGdTaEZrl2EE9xaZAFtH4DBMoSafxqkVyCtSdyztGmO2O5uXcM4i8QdLnaIlr8j8NWdmzC87US2oHXX4fJB6Gdj/zCetWL6Aw)
[Generator program](https://tio.run/##nVZbb6NGFH7nV0ynijQD4wRMoiiWeOl20@7Ldl/60jSxsBkSNvZAAO@SWP7t6ZkLMICtbmtFynDmO/c5l@K1fspF@P6ebYu8rFH1WjlpmW/hsC1ekaFmVVFmW86Q4E2tjo6z2uTr5yp74yhCoe/kaVrxuoKPu@CazUM2v2FByK7ZZcCCG3bjB/fOKq4keu44v3785c/fott4U3En4SlK@Gr3SNyGLhwEvyxFCqG/5A@UiloCHIV/5IKXcc2JYXjc5Kt4g9b5TtS8rBSt/Yju/HsXLLRwRcV3Sa4c0VibIF24t9FpnG00TJ2i4W1rSvKlFzeitRxpXiKBMoHKWDxyAoHx/YD2Tsr7r/LeBLO/UTaCYV3QXeF9dQbXEDMZX9clxSygZ0UUBUN@AzK5JAWdXh@x/TwuCi4SgE/QHLJ3XIZOJ/7SR3WB4fEwVMDfWecEPcps56LVTgQr6BTepvju61no33tRMEGsSh4/O6ctNpbeQmKNicI9YZ9KvmWQbwwy74A3a17UWS70E@g/I9shTz8m9YgLVXugh0Dit7tNbDJS8npXCmSI5yUvNvGaE3yBGb64wLSnPADFdbEpivUTXz@3sphgvCn4GhLJaqja6HMuuFGwzhNZh1P9Rn2129Rwz7/FGyKxtC3KVuJPkQb1sdRxTLGyQYWKJygXStUC7eW/A6YTuIj24sA6udG@PQFRq4j2@r/NDZZIl45lUtJ7IG@ymgQmPOmn6i9e5qQZhRmT4IIE3r45UIod52eU5LwSNfqel8@qJJvIbwX8IfhRfskMvI5JgdGEfUyZz8CAET1QdH9Cn5@ghyfo4oR8SQ8kXto5viRiFlIAXB4R2N6FUmh/Kd02RtvKFHlqsyKHx8nasuAYeT41WN319k7Y2qsryWqyfMvLbVyTroiZbqZMNsdR5rQUSOBeXh4eiHD3Hd/B22vOWXCgZ8ev5Ivp42Q0hxAkNlduMhwG0HCRqn1Mp8BQA30AhhIo8hrNZ1bDOMZ01TNd/TCTZdK1bZIJWiYS3a1V12/HquwCGKvjGxzNWLqbBf08S9Q849@gC/OEtIgFQKz5sgLmaWISnZMOJbXJaprtVwfqkn0NcX6bJbKyWoi0IhlVX@jDMNRggPbN0ZtBd5zZ7ZJ4QCGd0x@7Ft36q4LySSS8AT3@sBuaOKgZzhrpdd/irT0lmnfn70/QBUkhoaOhSqeTvdus7EkLja6JIn@INhZ5YJKHvbZ0U1kM0EzpAxSkl2J3Xxyw898G@3Q8vkS9Xc1wHGrvXv7dOyVn4OEL/V8Ovcway6WjQTOvQkucpPn3WCQfyjgFS8mwFWBPDwFQeXl9BSopdQMfDyBIQsQZ3HuBbPZS@DbORLeDdjupY20Wo9jIJWNEultc@fcM4fPzczxgtd4XZtZrG4DaFQgg7ZG2D1XOdFV54@r2TgXF6XdtbAQsELbJg1VBa0w@PMWlXJsnGwuBerMLkKpvW8nfYsPFY/0E5sOB2ALpCKjXlRDJVgOGL1pBr7edpyc2Gi2iA2oiiMnSV5uqMjohL35odS/afWmkxVSxbNGnFm9tHcK8LPMS4iBX3QHAAQHLpYi3fLmMIrxcyle3XGItRj9B5/39Hw)

Comment: Very nice for a first answer! Unless I'm mistaken, you could probably use `0^((n-t)^2)` for finding a truth value since `0^0 == 1` and `0^a = 0` for `a>0` to make  your approach even shorter.

Comment: You can get a prime by adding `n//12+31739` to all faulty test cases. So the last part becomes `+(1//(1+((n-360)*(n-523)*(n-654)*(n-941))**2))*(n//12+31739)`, for a total score of 408, I think.

Comment: Great solution! I have an idea for a shorter if-else gadget replacing `b*t1+(1-b)*t2` with `(C*t1+t2)/C^b%C` for solve large `C>max(t1,t2)`, say `C=9^9`. This can then be recursively expanded to a sequence of if-else's by replacing `t2`. My hope is that since we now write the condition `b` only once, it will turn out shorter overall despite the longer "gadget".

Comment: Another alternative to `b*t1+(1-b)*t2` or `(C*t1+t2)/C^b%C` is `(t2*(C+1)-t1*C)%(C+b)`.

Comment: Or, maybe in your case it's best to just change `b*t1+(1-b)*t2` to `b*(t1-t2)+t2`, and make the repeated `t2` be the short alternative.

Comment: These are a lot of great ideas. But I decided to stop investing more time into this. So feel free to use my sources to derive and post better solutions.

Comment: Here is an idea to get rid of the faulty cases altogether: multiples of 30 can be added to the offsets without harm (to each offset independently). You get other faulty cases then, but my generator program fixes them automatically.

Changing one offset by 30 does offset a grid of primes, pseudoprimes and non primes by 1. So you have 8 stacked grids, that can be moved independently. The goal is to close the gaps and to hide pseudoprimes behind primes. This should be even possible with a smaller number of grids, resulting in a dramatically smalller formula

Comment: More parameters to tweak: all Fermat tests are done with base 2. The base could be chosen individually for each offset.
Some grids could be reversed by replacing n with (1000-n). This might be beneficial because the density of primes decreases.

Comment: @Sisyphus: 0^0==1 is not specified and mathematically doubtful.

Answer (score 14):

## Score <s>163</s>,162

```python
1%(4^(n*15+701)%(n*30+1403))*(1%(2^(n*30+28)%(n*30+29))*(1%(4^(n*15+6)%(n*30+13))*(1%(4^(n*15+9)%(n*30+19))*(1%(4^(n*15+5)%(n*30+11))*(1%(2^(n*30+6)%(n*30+7))*(1%(2^(n*30)%(n*30+1))*(16)-6)-4)-8)+6)-16)-1374)+n*30+1403
```

[Verification](https://tio.run/##XZHdisIwEIXv@xRDQDrTqjS2/oJvsM8gVDfVQJqGNC4r4rN301azKOQiM2fON5OJublLo/Ousk0N7a02N5C1aawD2RoraxGJX2P3jLGOT7A4oE74Ml1nnCb@mmcpL7KcKEGvLg5jarF5iYvtU3oZV8GWfyjboHx6lkHhH40Cbf0uBMOQXtHMn4JmG/KOWR/zfF1QGubv/PPmrbPSIEVRtRc/pUKmyvr4XYLesbTfwdwKo8qTwPgQT@MkicnXWtFelYM93CvUBFVjQYPUYEt9FsinwDO/qkfkV6kdVvFdCY2jiR7wLVsn9cmBvtZHYdt57JFjaakUPn8AzQg2A3j0@jpPOruLb90j3wZkyKaM0X9MQxzYfTG9RmJfA2cH9xH4YNT9AQ), [generation code (takes around 20 seconds to run)](https://tio.run/##tRldj@I48p1fEYFaScB0J9DTNK1lH@5u57Q67d5IdyetxLAoIYZ2d4izsemBRfz2uSrbSZwA83HS8UAc16fL5apyJT/IZ56NP39eF3zrrHfZSnKeCodtc15Ip6DJbkU7CshzWkSSFyVsu0s1gElaNKhWfBuzLJKMZ4I4ecGBiewYoGRbw1ActvmhpGEiLwDiRMBFLNX4AtZmlRAnYW9M8EKUHMVBdDoJXTtrWmwj6eUk8p86DvwKKndF5uT8kxeRfBiS3J/NQoN8hs0ucMBfJARVGmq1vNyvQEbAv4sdtQW@j1JBO51ffnNmzsNDRxYHzU3Ri5l@qJnojbNEzPSjQ/crmksbFxgcTxZm/b6GneAOy5x5SCYkDEk4JiEMpmQ0JqPpotZfc5rzBRIzRciQsIiyDfXCIAgHv/zm4/KrJY6DPhtw/1TxQKK4JhqRUWBZqNZvzkn8dTnGzFoKiX0nyhLAzbhE/Erfk96pDZVaLeFxwma/8ozWOwYShINTTw4AQTK/GQeE392NA3tHji9KnxdLH4IaKXW8lwHzr0nW6/Ji8n@WbdnPSF9F2XLF32gBwoWR2nNitlHmEtsoTRtizkxurA143suQOT84oYN6wPBHBxQI8A0hSn5cKyl8owFLaJR6RjRfrwWV6IFXPM4os41YxrIN4AG611iwPjifnllKS3a1E8VUSCCqGFQAjqZFMze8Ufn@GZMSalkBjj0YoomCv4YwZ9hyM/8MHyyZ0syTPhgSB6jvBbbWUuRFoFoOSLCCSG0ypKwXrld3CwjgBh5n82Dh28c6kzBJKmV84zc8TelKen32XTvXi9PoGXFsQ2jK@cuCMPjz24786C@@2dOj7OCht89fF43DZkS8LhaK@NXmXjqiWdLou9dkob3A4azV48JgMAXDM3sONMvCA/Q/aX9mDTh0JCDDsNqqZ7p69Xh5uoU5NH4zwnPLwcGQGCatyDQi3L9lQuxiJBUtl2xkpHJS3O7yJJLUs7fanE5DgE4lMFuCylrXlEcJxKKIxCoMkj5Zg9eK55niTZ4pgmeuaxSAuBVzQXFFB3ErZMJ3EtSMpDyY9cFSNNGTeQKu67kD/TJwfcct8eIq0tZZmcSAH5CoxDECn8zBcJ2a04eCbwoqxJMT3AY3LqFZMnM/Fq7W4w35aC4w0vzU8QW73OKfZ8ctjKNxrcZbAJhopL7HhpF/d@fF8LC3CzB@dN6auyKDC/wtGhkMJVAFt@HluCWDs2lcxVtwKWq1DLN2P@7DeD76h3PU9jnV5rm5Ddc3N@4NeqpZkFqP3zKZNtYAVl69HhhNIYlf2w0j09jerTxA@1DDv9uk7xUKTVxzaKAO3e4kXXJwWkHetP8Zr0vBCsZR74PxKLjso8AxwXirOelCFdwN06t8Bk8TcrdeO5948Srw/G0PDpS4WyhpUyeScDQiE6RzjB06VFyuhG0BzTNtQ@oAgL/lLKN76aUNJzKBonW489soz8GgAGh70NuTyQ/EJW4dT1ReTMG0UNQ2SuROp2fZdT4cTYkzhEjqhA8hjCCyOuEY/6YACO8REE4hG3V6lsm9x37/we97k35/hCGuhyL3QSMXT2ANvVKdfXgZVsFH1@EVzvjLOBXe/dfxKtx334Zb4T808B@@hF/RTL6PpvSEMhXuA7IPyX5E9mOyvyf7d2T/QPaTb2FTlw9yl6eq3N8PuNaKKPf8k@Xe/IqEBbmScn3Y82@S3dPCr63g60zqM1JfriAtLjdcSpqBQ9YvLdiyoBBfVF46n2xcwBr8zKXrIp@jdVsABCyaCEAbcQk2DqYaYQ7Q0NLnLC8m8HM0rD0WbYazGT6g0mkyuUJ9@aJWl2zqQmbdCdUlDu4LAyC2LoffqOalNT91rjKoCVtz36s1s9S9IkXt305QU86pupds96r6afYSVF1EoZLJJK5uhQHc63vl3ve537yd@GWpR/d5yguKKQty0gxbBmc1E9eF6vBSLcpWABsFOsNv9@rygs0Zb7tLiRcOPLaCnanqWKZpfRJCPB71@6g3vPrtLLndlykSHqVC@qFxY1Pf6BcOb57vtHKZ7vCAGcqR3hNG2IqMA5@YpoEpiEvVvpjz8DJkbwiJG/lw06zCSkU3zRnUls@fFl9NfzGJOaQrvlYNlovR7dTpIfBdp/cHWg/MmTIhPbvXBW4jiNrx3quqKTu9rLReL9a1gs6JK9TjAqmJ3a@6tFLjLCAxVoul/6yIrmXW7vH1dHf84@SaeImeHzg/QFyzMoCKhUH9jlrE1rsOxBmBahktDIBwCtNzTPoq3avkP8Y/NVoABiI48zG8PwDGPTyxHLiH8QSLhgniTJw2F82kyUlj1bXGMJyaWkNjTr4FMbQR3znXtdeENZbNbtJQbnIJsaXbZcTx1xDDybWVTCaqsKqRwsewrMGmoYEHgI2X2959CCiehyuFA@Z404kZTMqZybgcICE65XiqaKYlhuaNo3ubSM08jptElaCJQVCKq5mwpMFFaZpHRWORVKppceXMY4tC2aXWTY/CSTUq58KKbnJRUkUymZbrqSgemhSl8tdJOjosXOsz1BVIKyU9WgEOQVmz3ntoFfMqWK1FGa6q6TlbYDiARJa1i3wrQHovJLD6DZCGoBQIzm@Pei38bL6IGBQz/5I8/1linx@CEtyGUp6amqgJMi1qjKKd8pbGd9iVpBJEVH05l4A8sGCc8tWrYH9iuTSG8KOsPayOb6i8Gqw9gqkHFSzGvjOEu8cIcUc482hiTTgd67NwDwTvYPw49Tt53eexb4co21bPVb2yEtknLl7xzi@CnThShd2o0/nbT3/5z991JaeyeELj3cbr7@uyTmE8tbpygKCzPpRAbH3w1gbffEpALY5rj/lfqGKqCgbx/FOjFZOrrzZgTg/oIf@3vneYyduC5mkEFUL3rku6d3ddv575HWb6/a6K@AmnIpPququvALNAfyH5WfzK5T8z6u1b/LvhzXF/6poPKYD0Xjf0q20m2sQEDWndzDer5AxnGDb6TnDL9ua15HXXOyKTfp@dfvey/rEiv7tjp8HRq5jgu3/TQAG4Bp98v2vZuvyABPXGgrzSwwz2w@zXGlsDHwTdJfwDWn9ctkArC4hdih2Y7nLZNd9p6NsysTvUVSxILraoYW8NzVlPC38JwzIebNxaSXLqVng0FdeojslQc7fQ6xb7Mo6wy3ZxyxK9Wx1b0cRcKFSPExJY61ZBPy2FLHTnGkWDEl/Usk2g9Dn1veXSH7SpG4pXZteD2o9hF4jF1u6Om21JOrZ7aXq919tow1at/TVHB9W76gm19EEAx8g@VoMhTAxhBtXJTV@vlx/eV2zPju7yE4OZnVzqOIsRSJOtIGJJmvz1OSowrp0daq8l21fv7buKzcUnhgkE5LIuxQ8HeLNwXTXkpkqta/uG/0ZkNTNmqzp4UbMUj6seavklhDcSTilwVWWOj5nJHTzdqbzD1ZeWjXyGmpS4O9GK0DCLXMvQrhiC237@/F8)

I would have posted this as a comment, except I only have 1 reputation

This answer is based on [Max Kubierschky's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/212389/95116), with many of [xnor's improvements](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213440/95116) (specifically everything in his generation program with the addition of his trick to shorten expressions within powers).

The main optimization is based on [Max Kubierschky's comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/212254/shortest-arithmetic-formula-to-output-1000-primes#comment499937_212389), and I found offsets `(1403, 29, 13, 19, 11, 7, 1, 17)` which are mostly small (with the exception of 1403) and have no faulty cases (these are just the previous offsets + 30).

### Explanation

This method works by generating primes of the form `30*n+(30*k+o)` where `30*k+o` is the offset composed of o, the base offset from the set `{1,7,11,13,17,19,23,29}` and k, the grid offset in the range -1 to infinity. The grids are the sets of integers n from 1 to 1000 for which `30*(k+n)+o` satisfies the Fermat test for base 2. The prime grids are the sets of integers n from 1 to 1000 for which `30*n+(30*k+o)` is prime.

The grid offsets were generated by first considering only prime grids (ignoring possible faulty cases) in order to find a set of grid offsets to cover the numbers from 1 to 1000, (in this case they were found by setting all except one of the grid offsets to 0, and varying the remaining grid offsets in the range from -1 to 66)

After finding grid offsets that cover the set, the code runs through all the permutations of offsets to find an order of offsets that covers up all the faulty cases (for the offsets used in the current formula, there are 81 that work), and then generating the formula using each to find which one turns out smallest

Comment: Welcome to the site!  I think combining aspects from two different answers is sufficient to warrant a new answer, but you can be the judge of that in the future.

Comment: You are very welcome. This feels more like a collaboration to bring this down than like a competition. How did you find the offsets?

Comment: You can still reduce the score by one by factoring out the minus sign from (-6)

Comment: @MaxKubierschky You mean something like this? `1%(2^(n*30-2)%(n*30-1))*(1374-1%(4^(n*15+686)%(n*30+1373))*(1390-1%(4^(n*15-9)%(n*30-17))*(4+1%(4^(n*15-7)%(n*30-13))*(2-1%(4^(n*15-6)%(n*30-11))*(8+1%(32^(n*6-4)%(n*30-19))*(4+1%(8^(n*10-8)%(n*30-23))*6))))))+n*30-1`

Comment: @Neil: Yes, something like this. That brings it down to 162.

Answer (score 11):

## Score 2341

This outputs all primes between \$31\$ and \$8017\$ (included).

```
(113467395935668970410160492737179506361846013862444084170197806945186405092696909126164158205176795679626257477170011681151081828693721528545308301463032313852735898720278373462178435545407324698821351304548663895918208828677426209417450978147368548225197577994423342074325769235860896833550745001703798952436205556087566508085462913775782980107289038262897153290911775461849717826677653709482106939563942394004153958440037041024098156603769869491411749714891362691603370984320936124882165280605174558859749487518953604842331779664328074931195219441658740089199947350409773050270253672458490842517716227535564556430387611590820439097600165832489226127768727315594781312368235772273799332206758908020271761747844563774441691210056862686595288936465304647859214996600265632129456351742413141396515373657806301978324762068082957610010981667490015017872109960968210719664738068557705903476757448731528153247317383397296951323720188125875523771873472067739298722926939700395850510069970848932566438053043914675253394668929358649440219868955587507427792258737478621439222869420782804120723724037942099140240986671113771843292946536125599661698395893047644516938416344212452574005345276922734768543821803294119263624051859444984143612848763146503016281898460776934493046854691490177334701465551154370051389269555217280444180285443508781807182786653180547028418689044382239111057385640034581765695611964566960423155654254631533264137376719604736646235721281638954806708051896372829794828522441565514326091912749474754904829505420000828614379978905433227551134966163328596138390836978449350464146519410700211096728982452219157828903470370081269726761212190236152174162025868830122533316205222356743692764196532590297434905214324476315471045728469350713970766245611550719074621408922145054478879292926089731205325210583591485438579344315785755440427094785080423582680705622279978441230497635622038519006130677863238128994042483893669828145180491933002965357145427263569009059259792273674006429955369804616413369843446578638589803530417606529429534136839003463278401805099943786536199970623822629008628461486362852575470843011844101058219237624888472496428195993935156341808156330726437453034634118080653972710684434727685175583816599255076497400463324245086662776394809313991656593421958024921754700582702681454016857120679602782/(208^(n-1))%208)*2-389+n*8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JZbZjlNHEIbveQpfEMkzI5LauhYR8iwgAlEi5Ikgyg3i2SdfOSBLPme6q6v@rf3Xh38/fPv49c@//3lze/7908vny7vL7fLut5erqkeWzxk/mT0loaIpMVZeWnMkPbUjRb3TIkI6tESnWnLiaGfIkbGcHBm11Aw9bXK0kgJ80tJORVFQRDVb9ai0tnWOl@mxPnFc2kUjXdyc4w49nJ4uE6v2olXT6vDD4pByi5xuUz/qwqvO9GYWCktv8argaBk6Dnqs1ihPzmqzwwinaibC3MOkwukyxzg0pSfbOUl2p9C411Dbwil4zmFFAdmRFuqljXpRr21aVMp6xJvDwVSP20KjLIgFk1csTNrL40V7zACY0JA@dDMh8HB4bvDm5GXFQqaVI3lmbLAfDWputWiOB@WBOt@KgMTYMGexACUASy4jcU73GXYF/SsTOWz3QkB7k8nGZuZxVaZV0GF3F21wxoAWnAitVDm0W4lRoSxodZAGsEJzmtUBvIz9wGdXwjkLTMLBohJMqQuFPYZmDCwgulzP4YxWV4MpuKiy1eKMu5lkoQgwX0mgLwZCEAFuUL2tIkAVOYlW@RxG6AaHAGiJZPEZ0xgGFbFkn6nN7l9sLDiWz@QBfZRyVuR@FzudFswndNsgE07RJQQWGVz0oBEG4N2koB2@lS6e5dTowxwCAE4VZBKg7yv71QZLlFXuU4aJELNhCtFuNaA/h8dSNkQtANjV1hS2nmMPAkEoB3YFEfHcYIqUl8uWndtRCqfCFNJam9usxtFACBQ3b1A0J0E8REAID77QYjh2m61R1yKYCi3yZTuM9QRvh/L/yxMwVPXeLTrimMUdcuEUKGCnt9WhpUpY44WTJulYEKWeDQnIc76tD20nXrdiJG1CAR8rQ6N0IkehEsqROi1yBlNXQh@WhDGMh7g3txDWcMAeurVQCHwhUjxfmzZMjjQD11CT@ABUXhE0OyqSQmtsI3QwPDVhtUkjnO88HGpwsi6ErKZR3AsEciAU6cMNzkCoh6pYYHBEkpSC4VB6HgxD4KECN2ITzSEP3b@jPlS7@gcaZLbBFigJenf2QfGGEmvDg6QkmckGRgF39Kf4YD0Oh4dxYzVLsyb822BkGY4qmmZyX7eevQruJPEMtAkWOLU9Zx0263o6BC8yAW1jH8ac3KTr5Q4h6eZf30W@oUXCA2ZZ4haG0BEsrQstnGNgJNib@LbC9H1FFSbGUZyKBAIk8Ae2YdCgPRbsgBHLNNgrqU8DkEp7pWuGStSxUG90c2TtpcGlhZw0FgNU3Uh8/2/K4z3O5RAMSx5xecRdcadWNb4jHdDBKVhDNpo28mMvCRIGHA5hZ3cwocBQGeHm@5LUAys8yeWEa5uscRBpMpT90b7BhCVgd69RNioZB6479CHU4QvwqEURRh@AqLsrcm2SYYNSQYqt90vX9zswxeYWgtm7U3wDAAEKdwBmJe9ZmEstNNESbcsKWTbbnX1r2NkYQXzImZsNInNBBpn1Xq9PV/icxW2@Y8tiB8GkQu6N0yQVYgpG4zompIhXMnbNtFcYUzIYp@2dv13ga/5CixuBsJoU3bRb9yvogxW3xYAApJJbO3@sUMEROhLOsTnh1lx6yIB7EDNAID0dDMzPGb23vG3i2FzImZvypZupOA4k7PbLlV8Ot8fH6@2N3h4eftqnh0e7vYGs29PtsW8vn5@/XvnxdNHbW35E/coXPLXfn54eLt9fXS4fn2/fnr98@vnL8x/X9x@ur7/ffjyw/vX3z9fbw4/3D29f/Xj5Dw) (Node.js)

#### How?

We compute:

$$a(n)=d(n)\times 2-389+8n$$

with \$0\le d(n)<208\$.

The values of \$d(n)\$ are extracted from a large integer, using base \$208\$.

Below is a graphical representation of \$d(n)\$. The minimum is reached at \$n=399\$, for which we directly have \$a(399)=8\times 399-389=2803\$.

[image: d(n)]

Comment: How did you arrive at this formula?

Comment: @Jonah This is essentially trial and error + a small script to make sure that starting at 31 was optimal.

Comment: I note you say "all primes between"... since the problem as stated doesn't say anything about coverage or ordering how far can you improve your expression?

Comment: Whenever I want to feel stupid, I look at your golfing answers.

Comment: @EricDuminil Much better answers have since been posted!

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd We can definitely take advantage of that. But this answer _is_ designed for consecutive primes.

Comment: @Arnauld I know, and I applaud everybody's ingenuity.

Comment: @Arnauld can you share with us how you make the cool diagram likes that?

Comment: @ChauGiang This is just a LibreOffice Calc diagram. (So I guess Excel should produce approximately the same thing.)

Comment: @Arnauld I think using Libre would be great, I found another solution it is using some libs like matplotlib for programmatically way

Answer (score 8):

## Score <s>1778</s> <s>1319</s> 1164

-459 inspired by [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil)'s suggestions!

```python
(28389416454731914904646197269110195258968918334324648337536406183122452341375087148095278619811035121264892162819521481008101705277372014120459537607320900170581458493476732106029764703970199356551116634482447603151892501883985471668745077729919867085592433543835805593713705073935219732297479335704578859520285745463599513991638068362975801056573234819165907183812641577379596655404026370719245188577913240916435487946831490476753322022399310328082542064590520714793222945825868990061383486920959013849054510725156607978917228480666383141633344797723352686825873369593489365635288158535711600587674466307031798274562517630853907709405080966507256977400682764885616947585079339593770144096628672186322100621135207302538190833576961188067354198288862669754543325834368496102584439249310678425485967421525911011440604945657742285226023738594503000443799738987162853276495354222398842865644351430245057910519732921873667017428523263018326208740011108682459267993023371456176948637898475810086660149605871207027333515638814123020249096374464098648830557815605475878366999652657721355174060931879798441836550660645385542381428064142926776728816247052/(14^(n-1))%14+17*n)*6-1
```

[Verification program](https://tio.run/##LZTNbhtHEITveoq9BCaVOO6/6ekO4DfJRY6lhIC4Iij5IBh@duUb2QeC3J3u6uqqGl5eX/572v3t4fp03p5fz5fX7XS@PF1fttPz5Xo63988fH68O3/5erftf/39drDy6tCMEdO1NVoiI7WnZauK9rBRndVa7uHGKT/m8AxJ3qlZDPNQ3klNjRJaZgFR9PtQU6OnTdNqwVGiInx0CpXTp4mGmsTo4TNluknL@3FpjIr2mMlblRTrmTHFe8KtfeQYqprpEWVBnbgOZdwQrfIuFuO4ZgyZc1o3xHJKjdEW7iO8fJTw6JMlhDIH15DAjWkxm6oJu1kFQxOrAVqkj@6hDmJ6SZYn5UCpwIpmZ1HORstEqFoy6Fj79uiEd0iIJSOnQgXS4M5WNBbaAmo1O8B9dwUFhsNIzBjpSGslZSNMcK@REpxF1mCNatiGa@iYyoZR2ahKHU/ADebJtKEjEbwn/k6zwr1EyzWSpTAcQERDAEvgwJzuCQyA7TnQwKp01EAibBAsg2gEIIJLOrsMsZJJk1fUocaUDnQmKciwWCRDAqbUEpUaqdmBlBwi/hpHj0asBsM900r2JEZpqr5Wd7GBxi213MpORU8hNSMwHJKVlsxhcVxnEcKcKJFKY0U4FixVc1YgKk6zhinpf78Ga3hKICzWckAGzEijT6eUbLmIgDKb2FRzESA6fO1DqDFpuVZAF6JRNzRgTN/AcRnvYeOKIG8STmUCA5x0kGK@jKuFQCRdlg34bckoILiL3JFE3cZjx8hayq0bhpOI1rk84XpNMczzZbnjGTeOdjg0qvqyDHlrye9chompNC6oSbCzu5MMsLuhN2YuOdCLhGJxBCxJNOFZYUQSNsYNtuCZr0WXXKyspMW6958@HTRubw/7Rz0ef9P4XeftfrzNj/p2vX/@9viyfd6@Pxz24/bwdN327bRv17v93/uD/rGxnB5/3PB/tr8cHj58f7zfDz@bjj@2r6fnl9P@z8u2fzt/ub8@//nhePOr9O7x8fDrb/Bw@Ql8eQf@2Xt8@x8), [Generator program](https://tio.run/##VY7BTsQwDETv@Qofm3bRNiD1gLQnPgPtIdu6EKlxgp1I9OtLmt0iuNmemTeOa/oM9LJtMwcPY1gWHJMLJOB8DJzgLWRKyKrqsvq4HoqTyM6jUvKVLaPABd5N/9zSk4E5MBA4Arb0gY05gel7o69qwhkoNqJfFYCbD8jjAMCYMhP0ZcFF8N9x6PZkN2ilJifJ0ngvrbzzeaitsrc@PrqqmxUsFm@/m9@I7oyi7G/IRZHsm93Utg5amCrCncpQKFhcyDbhn6xW5V9KNXPMd5jeth8)

This only considers primes of the form \$6k-1\$, and yields the lowest such prime larger or equal then \$102n-1\$.

---

## Score <s>1635</s> <s>1604</s> 1572

The rules don't explicitly forbid this, but it I'm not sure if this is intended. Similar to the above, but finds the next prime after \$\lfloor n^{1007 \over 621} \rfloor\$.

```python
16921707110807543794883034080662369959145330548686331531608873466161289588508225504395036067059456808254955842748011935275567235182962066696532824341658478313282515740212407513889626921371569995949618530076057857935444678903541507451833650971208966857022879588416744784446458319742198436165114149099979782639487537376816458053319371322652945071076875723112404278546530735706274859341438493065587724231536852995916148117098900150719957460662049351379626720184420298531075385276847667099516667910747707987556366430526973567431116704034575028503641091403375164564764095445312182120994347975065105984011801750777939791614004132127064169527985645152866679765959804131578103751126570294714529430395223496169502308685883689716858687150949295161789378929626842080159238203320971831181073359220269422355146095712138282898528757872049694061460608989183240128781928642651093781146703726149529559745625017336481225823115996890606949461379145867395915059579445847541041812545106491388887871854979774599921555206338249335536406513747513391059876604297546812682955845160908578873034957552441194311592692169821206761814295401029352512438888121121058993809853128792382425425507315758921975340564810424303160455069096558687026616771028629060280318800048984850429104924036193703515227460262324051154267318767728375732829596082819890956884172016068499243733410402170378286724312471419805200183238726658173781500929626384453831442841099333236763065428542599128063204447946777048377374390957947246087390567878387147899066382490069914521762754275957918350785590249135/35^(n-1)%35+n^(1007*(621^-1))/1+1
```

[Verification program](https://tio.run/##LZXZTlxHEIbveYpzE3kGJ6HWru5IfpPc4BiSkWBAA75Alp@dfHWw2M5pqmv5l5rnt9f/ns7@fn95etxe3h6f37bT4/PT5XU7vTxfTo93V/dfHm4fv3673c5//f2uY5mWlKpMqQyvFXO6ePA@hvlYK5dGukvGHHO4a7oOmbM8xtChNlfOmTLNMiV8pfiQUZIrckzOM1bmDKuYoro8rTJHmadOW8OoNNZIt2nhoYPYmq79npoVYmpBe@pzEt49e2nSG83FGjrTRWpI1swif0SMmkt40pQK6riPlFVqQopBmJjN6s4pWEHBvhRJ3VVhumY406VqaCyhVK2aNhyAKr28xtSOF7BhpqJdG2nMDJw0QxQTanfO5DODAaWcwqOByMWk4TOWywCdKgtrbOnNdtCHxlTIWQwiPYZyXDGaF@EacFSjUSZK8ya2wIHS6aSggagBC1xS8K3Ff6Lges1G38cIOAVMegIAOgUHCajPSrHZLIYK5Is72DPrIGPIAl7qGNyB5lpQBjTJFArlM6AYmjmoggtg60lEAoDUmB68F/3RLCk1be7d1UiGnh0G5VOlayqIQtSKQoL8QZhcNW/OSSLmgibhENTgth/BHaxQhfXcigqcn1YZgEA@SC7zaQxlrQf4VqqVO@dgOFZQIFMBGrgZk2C@aNea0lkNPlEyOgQjwA9ZoBkn0PhioLAGoysjH1D1MqJpHR@grhyWIIQkYRjXzNZJrsUQJCT3itHkMvQc5S2GBFqkDfLQiqrBiasJgAC62hgYktHRWQuVGijWNDNxlzMCgmEqKjZPjhL47WtnDJkgUSgMJA1MtrsV9GQJRmmnowrKkywCA8fe7u7DsXYVjMKESpIEBgjD4ony97aAkG/JuZZP2TXazmsSggl6aVRzTgC2Q70h2cDQUxNOG0HIwIPtE/iFJOgvXAbU1pDZJG5OQWXQgbl6HhIsWMHFEMEqQGrW9jHWGueoi@LAqwCA@yaCq145wA2rBpPQsdhgbIj2GMzgVlJifm8GpFcnHNMF5mWqlim3cBWGRRKOWAbbDKpRQop86BDTYyCEh2lnWwxqCAbDXgWcNShrgRLUoTaWE4LATUznRS52rOxqoCytohAQg/1JQWWTLTAZO@cCbi0jOmXrkLd2GdEcoE/EKNbqyZsbz@vrw/kPPf7m@fnMs7JRrw/D9Pqa0@PNjX7W98vdy/eH1@3L9uP@cD5u90@X7bydztvl9vzv3UF/37ilx59XfNScXw/3n3483J0PH5eOP7dvp5fX0/mf1@38/fHr3eXlz0/Hq1@htw8Ph1@fUId@fz5@ZH/es38kOL7/Dw), [Search program](https://tio.run/##ZVJBbtswELzzFVvkEDJRZQvJoTCSvqDIB4oeVhIVEbWWApdGLBh@u7ukFNlFeBCE5czuzCzHKfaeni4XN4w@RKDDME6ADDSqLvgBeEqF5XYMbrAB6d2qpTJg7JXKdYZXYZUYAk567zjqK1xvC6i2cqqtMQW0cRrtq4AdxcYo1doOyB5jJmgyOwVy7qBz1DLE3gIPuN9bXiTATyD4cLGH2hGGCdhiaPrMcu1xFjLXWFTadpbCBdBjZTIs2HgINLfj30L6o1Qiikr19ukkS6@y9Oqr6s4HQHAEV5wAV/G/vP8LGEGEQxewic4Tz6qr8odYwE0t36p8zoTUrb52G/CYOsoorVFEb4STorstPJtlWPbd5WWU702rsYDapN47aDxFRwe74kb/sWyq23sf9Bs8PIAWLcaUyMmiXi2unJRSk1jrklIbyeATcZfms5fVzAvCcZT4GQYfrCwQCTw1tpBfx9AgRagtHNi2t/r3ljTb5d00xsC3vI/t7ouJVp4XSsPkZBH3PTtbETWylcsU4wo2t8My4AWO1wTTSU8g3fxXlAmS@v3pvDmdd3A635eyLAk751xkvDGXyz8)

Comment: You can easily reduce the score to 1536. Instead of adding at most `58` to `n²`, add at most `65` to `2n²`... but you're always adding an odd number between `1` and `65`, which you can encode in base `33`.

Comment: Better still, I've got it down to 1481. Add an even number between `0` and `56` to `2n²+9`, which means you can encode in base `29`: `([1463 digits]//29**(n-1)%29+n**2)*2+9`

Comment: Actually, you don't even need to resort to `n²` - add an even number between `0` and `38` to `58n+1`, which means you can encode in base `20`: `[1301 digits]//20**(n-1)%20*2+n*58+1` for a score of 1320, I think.

Comment: @Neil your last suggestion looks more similar to Arnauld's answer than mine ;). I got inspired by your comments to rethink my answer and got a similar score by only considering primes of the form \$6k-1\$.

Answer (score 7):

## Score 194

```python
1%(2^(n*30+16)%(n*30+17))*(1%(2^(n*30+22)%(n*30+23))*(1%(2^(n*30+28)%(n*30+29))*(1%(2^(n*30+12)%(n*30+13))*(1%(2^(n*30+6)%(n*30+7))*(1%(2^(n*30+10)%(n*30+11))*(1%(2^(n*30+18)%(n*30+19))*(-18)+8)+4)-6)-16)+6)+6)+n*30+17+702*0^(((n-360)*(n-523)*(n-654)*(n-941))^2)
```

[Verification](https://tio.run/##ZZHRboMwDEXf@Qq/VLXDmJJA6Tqpf7IXusIWiZgopA@o6rezFBiahmTJkW@Or27ihvDdcT42vrPQD9YNYKzrfADTO29snTTntrKXawX8/jGqHWohkEUuU1XSbjkdiQT@1bT@1XS@0d5W7fRfUyunNtxqt3FTcqXURlvd1OSWxUEaq6CspCxmSOdagqRHqYWMMCJneSkjwdkhhnj28lBM/VQ8bYSm0df9rQ1whnuDTNB0HhgMg6/4q0b1AkpKRY8kPiUHbPb3tmacIXrA1fTB8GcAvtlL7fvXPSXL1aptcfkBdPNiNy2eWRp/AA), [generation code](https://tio.run/##pVffb6NGEH42f8V2q5MWAxd@xBedJV7aXqp7ud7LvVyaIGyWBMVeEOCEFPlvT2d2F3AMtlL1CTwz38zsN8PsuHipH3IRvL6mZb4l1cu2eCHZtsjLmmRVUWZbbhPBm1q@GsZqk68fq@wfTkISuEaephWvK/hx413ZfmD7n20vsK9sz7M9eL01VnGFtr5h/PHltx9/htfxpuJGwlOS8NXuns0bc2nMspRINbzOIJKoUW5Is0ImCBFZmpfb3SZG@5LXu1IQLflY8mITrzmjF9SmFxfUHCR3IJnPqXa2fuDrx86RLWzeFHxd88Su4Yjht1xw9L7OE8x5HBkDV7tNDUr@FG8YGpoy@87RL6GywIOoA6ZUBiVpnG14QnJBELUkLT72kNhgKMJW7O3eV9h2byBUbsNWPRUO4mLeGEv7wJ@o4U1WM08fOv1a/eRlzppD5ijzLphntc3eNKlh/EqSnFeiJs95@Yi8kiZ0O/Rfgo/BiKTG7DzyW16Pwd4HwEJMQ1dDp0ddatquDVkfyT0pd0dy/4Q8OCEXJ/yj3EP72bGGCScwQXs54a3TBehxUOJxdcaHkaR4nLAUB9NilZY3JfaPspWKIdkRplMtEKeb4pqX27hm/Qdtq2/Zxg/2sFzKBZS8Rc3@jol524P2Vqtgjrc3P0yrsMG6ToR@eH9c3Tz/O3RPlA4dQGlsX5Jr08CDOUfkdKPm2DBQhi4YBmgo8pr4TlHxXZKfBC0G0OLdoIOUrg5T6sqVieS79PAdFUxRpYcRhQ8Rv7yEZILomYxTAXXjQieKa9BrBxZY0bbez49ZTOQnjnMGBpv2e@N4t3LiHIIt5jngwJyziUxulhoyICj61ZVWUqjS1Dn9o4NG0amjenhWOjoAzBl1ABKG5MQRQp3DcGtAGFty4qlJy@HSQgSCVtEqLjHYVDMP3EpbwZ@jqoYL7V5m10os8BxFDkPnpmnJGJ39@YQGb9AWR/RNshdMsVeU/CkCOghed0D7JJ3AmLaDVkRDdclkaXqK5oGkwaxNHOVF6o13cnemYMd8YqS3sU8zDlT35jPjv3A9GzhLxsTr5SB6zmBd2NURb9a8qLNcVPLrG1VkCGS5sJwcLiuWAwIHOq54ic66Ha0mE2ZA5BvMza3MlQgsdRmLe85g3Liuhz3SdCvN2chq18FxpndDdbPr5YP2hksKu1WjFpEO@zEuCi4SxlDT3QdferXsVOnzq0g4puNODDjAYvaDV7kwhv2Cypq3Y41a1Opu7BSvQViwzDu4h62UztvCwT3kuJ5Y@TfEUevK9efuHWN4j35yYcoJZ@EH8vlpcSmfny89EzzjLqX5w@qfrqFF3sYx1NpLNWRJsAukqF8@1/lOwDL4@0NcVoPzoXvYUTeZ8nfn@G@x4eK@foDawAs7dGYeGKnOCsgTLytZSWzG6/5EEzuxgvZG5pkuK4Yu662PO6owhz8BhPKyzEvZToX5@vov)

This is golfing down the [excellent solution of Max Kubierschky](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/212389/20260), who said they will no longer spend time updating their answer. See their answer for an explanation of the strategy. The formula here is largely the same, but was shortened by removing repetition and introducing cancellations.

**Branching**

The main improvement is the arithmetic formula used to branch on a condition:

```python
if b1: t1
else: t2
```

Previously, this was done as `b1*t1+(1-b1)*t2`. This meant the condition `b1` needed to be repeated twice, which was costly because the condition of Fermat-primality used a relatively long formula.

We instead regroup `b1*t1+(1-b1)*t2` into `b1*(t1-t2)+t2`. Instead of repeating the condition `b1`, we repeat the output `t2`. So, we arrange to make `t2 be short.

As used, one of the branches just gives a number (the successfully found prime), which the other branches into further conditions to continue the search.

```python
if b1: t1
else:
 if b2: t2
 else:
  if b3: t3
  else: ...
```

Our method has the no-result `t2` repeated twice rather than `t1`, but we can fix this by negating the condition `b2` so that we can interchange `t1` and `t2`

We make it so that the twice-repeated `t1` is just a number, while the once-repeated `t2` is the long branch. We do this by negative the condition `b` to checking non-primality rather than primality. This is done by replacing the `1/stuff` check for `stuff==1` to instead be `1%stuff` for `stuff!=1` (in both cases, we know `stuff!=0`).

Doing this recursive expansion, we further find that it has terms like `t1-t2` that subtract two potential outputs. These can be simplified. Because each possible output has form `30*n+d`, we can cancel like `(30*n+17)-(30*n+23)==-6`, saving many instances of writing `30*n+`.

**Error fixing**

We use a variation of [an idea suggested by Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/212254/shortest-arithmetic-formula-to-output-1000-primes#comment499884_212389) to fix the faulty cases in a shorter way, using 32 characters not counting parens.

```python
+702*0^(((n-360)*(n-523)*(n-654)*(n-941))^2)
```

There are four non-prime outputs, and a brute-force search finds that adding `702` to each one makes them prime and distinct from all other outputs. We use an indicator function of being in those four cases, and adding `702` times that indicator. The indication function uses `0^` to check `==0` for a product of `n-k` for each failed input `k`. (If we can't rely on `0^0==1`, we can use `1/(1+_)` as a slightly longer alternative for ``0^_`.)

### Potential improvements

Other potential approaches might hide errors in a more efficient way by adaptively adjusting the numbers checked and the base of the pseudoprime, as suggested by [in comments by Max Kubierschky](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/212254/shortest-arithmetic-formula-to-output-1000-primes#comment499937_212389).

---

### Score: 181

```python
1%(4^(n*15+8)%(n*30+17))*(1%(4^(n*15+11)%(n*30+23))*(1%(4^(n*15+14)%(n*30+29))*(1%(4^(n*15+6)%(n*30+13))*(1%(8^(n*10+2)%(n*30+7))*(1%(4^(n*15+5)%(n*30+11))*(4-1%(4^(n*15+9)%(n*30+19))*9)+2)-3)-8)+3)+3)*2+n*30+17+702*0^(n%941%654%523%360)
```

[Verification](https://tio.run/##ZZHrjoIwEIX/8xRNE2KneKEUVEx8g32G3aAWJYHSlLpZY3x2tgXBW9KE0m/OmTOtuphTLXmb67pCzaVSF1RUqtYGFY3SRSU88af0FmPcMp/ElBJJWRKswbcbHgZsBUDJM2JsYBH/YPHI0ne2HC0H2bpHtnhAH82SUcQcimfPMB2ha5aC9ZlxmK0h4G7RKLiPEKzCiIZO5qcx85dJ7CcR9/kyhNZOPm@MLhQBz8u34jcrCS6zanfIkNzgwF2PJVo059KgLbrmRALKa40kKiTSmTwKwqaIhSGDm2fvVBqST66lkKQXwQ0disYUcm@QPFc7oZv5xFr2pVlZkvtTENUbq86419q6g1DdI/64KDaB@8y1UGW2FwRTiqf4G8PjZLGwJwtslTbD0ZysxIV5sXlUE1v8rIbuf4z3ooJhPPzVOW/QtW9xw9D@Aw)

This includes some hand-found optimizations. First, the faulty cases are checked in a shorter way found by Sisyphus, as `0^(n%941%654%523%360)`. This evaluates to `1` exactly for the exceptional inputs `n` of `360, 523, 654, 941` and zero otherwise. This mod chain works because each value happens to be less than double the previous one, including if we append `1000` to the end.

Other misc fixes uses that some values could be written shorter in base 10. Some of the expressions within the primality checks like `2^(n*30+16)` could be shortened like `4^(n*15+8)`. The various difference values were all even and could be written halved with a `*2` later. A `+stuff*(-18)` was changed to `-18*stuff`.

Comment: Amazing how short it's gotten, nice work! I believe you can just write `0^(n%941%654%523%360)` for the error fixing condition [(verify)](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SCFPITNPoSgxLz1Vw1DH0MDAUNOKizMzTcFAS0sjT9XSxFDVzNRE1dTIWNXYzAAkx1lQlJlXopGn@f8/AA "Python 3 – Try It Online").

Comment: Absolutely amazing! Since there is a law of diminishing returns, one can imagine that it will not be substantially beaten.

Comment: Nice work. Against my promises, I couldn't resist and did optimizations myself and came to very similar code. I didn't notice your answer, so I posted mine, sorry. You might want to integrate my improved offsets with only one faulty value.

Answer (score 5):

## Score <s>3627</s> 3611

<sup>-16 thanks to ovs</sup>

```
3+2*((673353961358307057272173964285854305022400426862712283607156657501677042657259951223221803215027383567602764647222388720899640048400919228204711994106584574819864931142671077276501015670240042908527525811814749482980228611256604904077801987663433451736668942035070032934698860829734874720469210161714878816011028172504741493933579809209910574296450420677024369299112300880495910602256708103075450576078270852444355116728596095883942463207003664230806032583002863238578022990852754983925220712751300313297384933847995017349232355819646993088732601141789442882215894245107446410040144336314519163731984860252867369601943162930927332772671777942282743699929467221065940282853778104585857297151693682829776011636408160070741255197392398379178628552688459418297270015040378809673826532754044991491047949801618973677882844224163396790251399862833397713210556181592058088280808086833457843140471319676974659849432132663508730287070561924395375776930976500890901210246692236611967263433823329001222292758613681022886491412907860270659758688163330174276013329990329027854152360352827518702283024606693537791396445418370900593234237528394888627532943238538996362251812152746408784587329522604812362612961371495908130917050336369858923800623610558102111936921275925428797115215197211803311011792800756612190446912977181671053858030216650244322510913097098308798280996846215666363104582951499187555401911800510241478422010155586326948174226637924523831893487438486345918123442987712606546163773523778000231233612013623430096825956978942500937017215764165647469497368906623052990700252559013399879211291330909786175176769030687149835775829911173638805247625058275472816919156779291864013317155789882424054286324759552057921576616305056718594449895582860551963359519586408623708864584561224246719261364576172798288646507616917260121960060868716498458065082069151627356119717481764663140004551411443836333454961570935788652411333156384108866105400945838983456882978708424835088504807894682236883745784973974040648206299840824904279658635709233240664508551436734587146655032803436637243796714343511860088974399527943200654250140528821734417790449393945285632254377776046148129706540302453728840180914936819379438129581929627122804300127402709137830767613859849789109693350209773812357814726116008525681439255652001075856620439770299106395170302718499156517954285958747428744867003478259930463719139124320607133501439062288308905310881240867020273433661589445461066595657102669091317184108354554780017050349715850637537754106644755877075976187792445454821491839099929811225904639357052860836725499598183388404838427261429247485564633277253719915506486176500112852688184110139443587654583288837334797167835735314125201482147157537170750071301166473892100288867902409680472473344928486818014572141062729317739432887663007563551474290116952695377398184560337726343710669752174924005456400102600864172580302332762119194992885413026313261935677976382585514252800149731204021813826627080668911910552674815596682803932260276187920122242385797617877679445263885318204673888387270960551456287016730721644217841772314017713996319546205478449021962852317888766140480391183821928016315770425629570172282014425326824523667359350036132550758310731296339346026078740156028410312853179295874487323332796505227759163992369277010277291451843685489537975456773437258824811891298037075841518405314798557707912615382278504559764233167102285790740913352590724521945879074542935442272119863497621828348597890290006456761410388942801963190048896271350965485295433493478609534842891151210843278069634083290205578635819949175811191179//(3963**(n-1)))%3963)
```

(Brackets added for clarity, but not counted in score).

This unpacks primes from a large number. There are 13 bits in the largest prime, but we can omit the last bit if we ignore the prime 2, since then the last bit is always 1.

You can also check the [verification program](https://tio.run/##RZdLbibVEoTHeBWeXMluuJB5Tr7OnbIBJiwAhBss0XbrbzNg9X2/KCOhlqz@q84jMzIiMuvz329/vL7sr18/3l4/3f94@/vz2@v3P789//n9y1@ffn263T9/@vx6e7t//vLT7fnT093db08f7z8@vDz@7@6b29PbX7eX@/3t@vDwUL137lO@c7a1Za9e3jyJNTkZ29LWCrNYNbXa15pd1p5V2Wle3XrHxjwneb3X8rG9nI29Z2d18b@Kil68nullc7iBQ4c/xw@HLot2PyfcKieyY/xMxdnunN9uTWzFjcbdbe8xHZtcnSvHfTw6Tsw6Q8hT7osgLY4Fe8c4rqt27B1JilU1J5btJG/iPTvqzJRxQO@YJlzj0eLC8naezHiZu61x0iXgcOI7QNjceZad40BIWBW8XiZwVmwO4Y2vbTZDQMkyMFnKY9wAPlmf4NSzWilFxM500KUMp@zkzCbaqL2ucIsCbRuO2UulIyZe7clW8ucfXOKwa@Vij/PTWbd9K78hcP40NTPAiEPduBHMKdQ5HD29l7INb3CCDkNhU5ABn3VQT6cE5oS6aztPj9fuDc4BjFw70KuI3k9sLxAGIwi3qCQF7W4Oo/IthA4YBeku1f8E@ZD5pm5ukaJiE7an19nFK360oqsNj1QWUKEcC9DIjmzIvA@hF8ck3IVScEv7QBgKEfmmoHaIceDvFlwWQaGC8oAM4Knyw3nUkfQHFFZwJfLoQ4K@z9EFmyfdAEv1kx2ecCHHtMeufzViXQ84hIgOSMjidJArpQi2gnbBRWAn95YWC2HEPqCQJCv0xH@0Y8ecu2ADzFpwwXXcurg9C4APGaK1BdyJEEDMJQnJiXryulWgFtJaIF6TA0SIJVR1AhTSOasxAU8uQSiqVTrByQR0vRHAVpWOyzKCpcBOeJYHPkFRtCnizsg8AFmpwtItA9iFBEALWsEB1RGAUrw7UBbl8oo1RcDkgAIRDrUGBwcdE@tQLJTkRLNirfBXqg4gUp1ID/8hb0MernHRg9cYFL4Cf/pQIvQHhstxCsjv4hZhyXMIlDqSq2N3ZEz0hEwAKobBMWI@qjLpTNSSLZbUINKShotP05lwC3lwr6UKh1UNZLrMjJCRbgGS8BcLCCqAfDbku5xoS1EQ6AitDQ2xMhQN/hkl0TXFkVgMI9gsAQoOBzwogcOimDwJ3yRfKHQoEhbmWA58TpyZvENEh1zFLkt5CEJBxQnqUAKqExcuRvJkT/4wCzq0iAxENaoQft@t1ElWJovdc1Z0cW2KPrgq0OL5cnEOJCUqz5FYbKIQLHhhMaaiAUtQQPSLOZ4rXGVL7dnrGCM2eYb3VKBM0ofGrHfsUnQiEdyU/6qhgIgOZuNZkgRyJP51lY8llJffBNZyPbiApZSE245qxEvApjcYS3AhfCwlO2xMdWO/LBD4gzDCZYr0yS3VB@xNyAIyXAQYTrab9KmqKzzRVn2QO9DFsAVFQkKEBkli5AqDYY2pftQSptMO@jIUuV3jKVah4ACengqEcJncStzS5XIF1qgvjSLE0ra05gSeaAkKQxVxD8thHy/4TQcCWG7nCgiATKVfE@2oJ/mm2oL6B12iJR@1QxLBdEtS4ayWUcNSqfnIckJ6ClyDvVQe7aiLYlGwkuO1TH0I0b@PGyYKo@SQY0G@1qQC6RxtyjwBBUWW2rDRgtGCRAI2iIxKqzfQDMGUlDCDpASch@aJsWjx8m4TYa0wW6yF8GCXlMtaHEJUhFWaCOQkgRbVgpGwZp5NcpiTHNCX0NF0pFh0HQUhyy3Pzq1is8S0fWk4UuOsq6eGdEx5pNLEd3CBo1xdgbBvMyAgHfT9bn2hXggnuFn2m5qa8F@MBmMgNToFtiMf4eSEGWpqGLFdfZZhidocBS5WqopQHUpQMKrMe9qVigP3YKBQxHLQYsAdqP7ewlNZg1GKekhJvYmD5@q2ChtzgwuwiLkrRW6ggLZoQm5cLa@ge6gjURK/oiQtZeRKwgSkejz@hDDoeKYTrt4bMjU6KUFxHuOLHJJbOYZJwYUHcTM8Qgdxdq7Z73J6DVaq5NHRcLrUYVmlmJM2t/u9lbYwpT/Cb85HoOSgoVXVgVI4JxhczUF44P1wABMlFLVMHpdmLZr4vpyu0TvrdblGI86RdrFpeI2tawgpDX@muVRnmeYWuQsGXJp5jGqpL66ruIwY6vFxDX2qN36BLMSlJdsFWA3VGm9AfTT2nMskyUIDBgVARzQ22gl7JeAlC3NNMurOuCgdzUQ7ADZZoooLpHOhqUlGMeERBO9qpJgz9dMHAXecvJqMRnvsELrAi6uvFTczH6TGWBCCQGgRdQgNObgmcWFMQqFhn6pTzy1qbTXsS4qhOWELeUwOBsPI1PwJ/ur8BEGdSOloMGXuKooyqvTRsE1BVGHqQUj6dlDXJxnRjsu0Q4KFqBRMiuI9SiVPDUQyeRAH@n1NCeRICZg/JVk6MdJqZeqy9OsFFkLCmh81fRw18yPKUFUafMrDTFMbUtL3kvhL2WjW@mxRKfStNJcjghsZswkc9C1zZET6QuAg1lOO1HBIyoRKt@IqtK1RztRfof/oM4tGp48mDSV9fvjhgfltf/jw8PJff3x8/I9@Pd7dfXy93b/cP7/c3355@f3pAQHad/YdS/iO/OXLl6d/PzEf9HX5@PXr/wE).

I do not consider this anywhere close to optimal, but it's a good starting point.